# Why is Rails rendering a 200 when it should be rendering a 422?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my controller action

```
  def create
    @book = Book.new(title: params[:title])
    if @book.save
      render json: @book.to_json
    else
      render json: {:errors => @book.errors.to_json}, status: 422
    end
  end
```

Here's my React code

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('here')
    Axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/books`,
        {
            title: this.state.title
        }
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

The normal response block in the react code is what gets called. I look at the browser javascript console, and the response looks like this:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

This is what I see in the rails console output:

```
Started POST "/books" for 10.0.0.204 at 2020-05-18 07:59:46 +0000
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"title"=>"asdf", "book"=>{"title"=>"asdf"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:11
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/books_controller.rb:11
error
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

So it's still setting a status of 200 for some reason.

Comment: That's odd. What's the Rails version?

Comment: I assume the `create` action you're showing is in the `BooksController`. However this isn't specified in the question. Is this indeed the case?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the code so that instead of

```
  def create
    @book = Book.new(title: params[:title])
    if @book.save
      render json: @book.to_json
    else
      render json: {:errors => @book.errors.to_json}, status: 422
    end
  end
```

I have

```
  def create
    @book = Book.create(title: params[:title])
    unless @book.errors
      render json: @book.to_json
    else
      puts @book.errors.inspect
      render status: 422, json: @book.errors.to_json
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is an exceptionally bad idea and you're not really fixing anything - you're just adding new bugs. `.errors` returns an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors` and in Ruby everything except nil and false are truthy. Thus you're checking `unless true` and will always return a 422 response. Also if your checking `.valid?` or `.errors.any?` you're only checking if the application validations passed - not if the record was actually persisted in the database which can still fail.

Comment: On top of what @max said `unless` should never have an `else`, this would be considered code smell and very non idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your action is being processed as HTML instead of as JSON or */*. Perhaps you need to add application/json to your request headers content-type?

Comment: While correct this is really more of a comment then an answer.

Comment: What would make it an answer, though? The problem doesn't seem to be in the controller code and what I have said will solve it. I am curious. Usually, I am the one asking the questions, instead of answering!

Comment: Right now the question is not actually answerable since the behavior it describes can't be fully reproduced. The wrong content-type is definitely part of the problem but there really could be more to the picture - as changing the content-type won't change the response code. Unfortunately a majority of Stackoverflow questions are like this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It could be just one of the issues or just a symptom of some other issue, and so not answer the question. Perhaps a moderator can convert it this into a comment. If I delete it, we will lose our comments as well (I assume).